# JQuery UI droppable draggable HTML got corrupted after several drags and drops

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

After several drags and drops, both areas (draggable- left side, droppable - right side) got changed. HTML changes on some sections on both areas (sometimes only left or only right area changes). It seems like all the sudden there are no margins between some elements and background becomes blue.

Is it possible to refresh somehow draggable / droppable areas?

Example is [here](http://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/YVzgbN?editors=1010)

Code for draggable - droppable:

```
$(function(){

  $(".draggable").draggable({
     revert: "invalid",
    stack: ".draggable",
    helper: 'clone'

  });

  $('.droppable').droppable({
  accept: ".draggable",
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var droppable = $(this);
    var draggable = ui.draggable;
    // Move draggable into droppable
    draggable.clone().appendTo(droppable);
    draggable.css({float:'left'});
  }
});


})
```

[image]

Comment: if you add .draggable { float: left; } to your css it works. The div which didn't have a margin was just as big as two divs and the div before did have the property float: left. This happened because the following div did not have a "clear: left" property. So you can either give all elements the left float, delete the float altogether or give the div after the float-element a clear-property.

Comment: @Kathara - it works, thank you. Can you please post your comment as answer. (I've added float:left just you've suggested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the float that some divs receive and others not. Either you add the following to your css:

```
.draggable {
    float: left;
}
```

you delete your float altogether or you add the clear:left attribute for all other divs.

If you add the CSS part you can leave out that line:

```
draggable.css({float:'left'});
```

in your js-file.